# How to specify nuget package version on push?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package, dotnet-cli

I'm working with .Net Core and am trying to create a Nuget Library.

I'm packaging my project with this command:

```
dotnet pack MyRepo/MyProject/MyProject.csproj -c Release
```

It always creates the file `MyProject.1.0.0.nupkg` inside the `bin/Release` folder.

When I try to push this package using this command:

```
dotnet nuget push MyRepo/MyProject/bin/Release/MyProject.1.0.0.nupkg --api-key ${GET_KEY_FROM_REPO} --source "mygithub"
```

I get the following error:

```
warn : Error: Version 1.0.0 of "MyProject" has already been pushed.
Conflict https://nuget.pkg.github.com/myrepo/ 307ms
To skip already published packages, use the option --skip-duplicate
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 409 (Conflict).
```

How can I avoid that? Should I go and manually rename the package each time? (it seems like a completely terrible idea to me).

Why doesn't it version the package automatically so I would be able to push a newer version?

Can I set it up somehow in VS2022 so it would add version to the name automatically on build in Project Settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `<Version>...</Version>` property in a csproj controls the package version generated, however: that requires you to manually change it each time; you *may* find it easier to use auto-versioning from source control, for example via tools like [`Nerdbank.GitVersioning`](https://github.com/dotnet/Nerdbank.GitVersioning).